# Change workflow stage based on content type

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have a `List` that is associated with multiple `ContentTypes`.  I would like to use the same workflow to start a `task process` with different users based on the actual `ContentType` of the item that it is running on.

Using SharePoint Designer 2013 with SharePoint Online

Comment: Could you please clarify task process ?

Comment: @XristosK It's a specific workflow option in SharePoint Designer.  For a single person, you can `assign task`, and for multiple people, you start a `task process`.

Comment: Will the http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114450/how-to-send-my-wiki-page-to-be-approved-by-specific-user-s/114548#114548 help y?

Comment: My question is about how to differentiate a workflow based on the underlying ContentType.

Comment: Could you please explain "differentiate". I can't undestand why my proposed solution isn't a solution to your problem

Comment: If(CurrentItem is TypeA) DoSomething(); If(CurrentItem is TypeB) DoSomething();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items have `ContentType` and `ContentTypeID` values that can be accessed in the workflow that will give you the type.