# How to send my wiki page to be approved by specific user/s

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, versioning, content-approval

I have the following inside my SharePoint server 2013:-

- A publishing site collection based on enterprise wiki.
- Inside my page library options, I define “Require content approval for submitted items” to yes.
- Currently when any user add/edit a wiki page , it will have a “pending status” and any user with Approval permission can Approve/Reject the pending page.

But I want to implement the following requirement.

- *When users add/edit wiki pages, they can select to which user/s they want to send the page for approval.*

To implement the requirement, I am thinking of doing the following:-

- Add a new site column named “Require Approval from” of type “Person or Group”.
- Then create  new view named “My Approval”, which will show all the items that are pending and have the “Require Approval from” equals the current user.

I did not try my approach, as I first want to know if there is a more out-of-the –box approach offered by SharePoint to implement such as a requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Sharepoint Designer workflow, where you can assign permissions (like approvers) to ONLY one person or SP group. So, I would suggest to use choice field. Then,in workflow, use  multiple IFs for every choise and assign there permissions. Don't forget to check the approval status.

You can also check free permissions workflow activities and see if anything is suitabe for you: http://community.virtosoftware.com/wikis/sharepoint-workflow-designer/permissions-activities.aspx

If you need more info, comment me.